# change textview when change static string variable in android

Tags: java, android

This is my main class. change textview settext when static text change in another class. Note: this process will be applied for several views

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static String text = "123";
        Button btn;
        TextView txt;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
             txt.setText(text);

        }
    }
```

Another class

```
public class AnotherClass{  
 public void changeTextViewText(){

   MainActivity.text = "bulut";
}
```

Comment: How about setter?

Comment: Why don't you use an interface if it has to be done for several views? Making every view static is not recommended

Comment: my views are not static. but variables have to be static. calling from a few different class

Comment: @FatihBulut i added  2 different approaches, if you need more information on them, let me know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not recommended to use static in `Activity` class because it can cause memory leak. But if you must, then make the static in your `TextView` not your `String`. Something like :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static String text = "123";
        Button btn;
        public static TextView txt;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
             txt.setText(text);

        }
    }
```

Then in your another class

```
public class AnotherClass{  
 public void changeTextViewText(){

   MainActivity.txt.setText("bulut");
}
```

**Recommended way**

Make a constructor in your another class like :

```
public class AnotherClass{
  MainActivity mainActivity;
  public AnotherClass(MainActivity mainActivity) {
     this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
  }

  public void changeTextViewText() {
     mainActivity.getTxt().setText("bulut");
  }
}
```

And in your MainActivity :
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    public static String text = "123";
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
         txt.setText(text);

    }

    public TextView getTxt() {
        return txt;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use static views in Activity but there's nothing wrong about using static finals like a RequestCode

Comment: as I mentioned the question had worked for the fragment. 
But I can't remember how I'm doing now.

Answer (score 2):

You should update your textview when you change your String. In your case, observer pattern is a good design pattern to accomplish this. Basic approach:

```
//create a class that stores object. 
public class Observer{
  private static Observer instance = new Observer();
  private HashMap<String,TextView> map;
  public static Observer getInstance(){
      return instance;
  }
  private Observer(){
    map = new HashMap<>();
  }
  public static void subscribe(String viewKey, TextView view){
    Observer observer = getInstance();
    observer.map.put(viewKey, view);  
  }
  public static void changeText(String viewKey, String text){
      Observer observer = getInstance();
      if(observer.map.containsKey(viewKey)){
          TextView textView = observer.map.get(viewKey);
          textView.setText(text);
      }else{
        // throw exception 
      }
  }

  // in your activity do this
  Observer.subscribe("Main text view", txt);

  // in your other classes simply do 
  Observer.changeText("Main text view", "bulut");
```

Of course you can use some libraries to accomplish this as well such as https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid . Or send your textview to your other classes as parameter of course

Answer (score 0):

Prevent Memory Leaks and do not reference Contexts(Activities)

***Interface callbacks method***

Better Approach would be :

Make a interface:

```
interface TextUpdater{
void updateText(String text);
}
```

and implement it on your Activity, or create a instance of it

example:

Implementation method:

```
MainActivity extends... implements TextUpdater{
...
..


    @overRide 
  void updateText(String text){
   textView.setText(text);
}
```

Instance method:

```
TextUpdater textUpdater = new TextUpdater(){

    @overRide 
  void updateText(String text){
   textView.setText(text);
}
}
```

Finally add your interface instance to the other class via constructor or setter method.

```
ex1:  otherClass.setUpdater(this)  // (implementation case)
ex2:  otherClass otherclass = new OtherClass(this) 
 // if you make a instance of interface then use it (change 'this')
```

In your other class make a reference to interface:

```
 OtherClass {

  TextUpdater textUpdater...

 add constructor or do  setter...
```

and then call the interface like

```
textUpdater.updateText("Your String")
```

Notes: 
Make sure you run on UI Thread

***LiveData method: (Better option)***

```
OtherClass .. {



  MutableLiveData<String> textLiveData = new MutableLiveData()
     ...
     void changeText(String text){
      textLiveData.setValue(text)
     }
```

Main Activity ...

```
otherClass.getTextLiveData().observe(this,Observer<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onChanged(final String text) {
    textView.setText(text)
  } 
  )}
```

Update your text like:

```
otherClass.changeText("Your text")
```